# Is there a way to init/call CTOR in the .cpp?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, object, constructor

I've these pointer declarations objects within the `.h`:

```
ILFO *pLFOPianoRoll1, *pLFOPianoRoll2, *pLFOPianoRoll3;
```

which I init in the `.cpp` with:

```
pLFOPianoRoll1 = new ILFO(this, 8, 423, kParamIDPianoRollLFO1, 0);
pLFOPianoRoll2 = new ILFO(this, 8, 542, kParamIDPianoRollLFO1, 1);
pLFOPianoRoll3 = new ILFO(this, 8, 661, kParamIDPianoRollLFO1, 2);
```

but I'd like to avoid pointers here (I learnt that "if you don't need them, don't use them"), and just use variable/class (due to manual management of the memory later).

But how can I decleare the variable of the object in the .h (such as `ILFO mLFOPianoRoll1`) and than call the CTOR on the `.cpp`?

Comment: Are these members of some class or global variables?

Comment: Using `extern`. BTW, any reason why you want them to be exposed in the header file? Sounds like the wrong idea to begin with.

Comment: @barakmanos: I need to access to that object on each part of the class where is decleared.

Comment: So this is not the header of class 'INFO' then? OK, in that case, why don't you declare those variables as members of whatever class this header file denotes?

Comment: It's what I did. But I want to decleare there and INIT later (on the CTOR of the class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use initialization list for this purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(int a_) : a(a_) { }

    void print() 
    {
        std::cout << "A: " << a << std::endl;
    }

    int a;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() : a(1), a2(3) {}
    A a;
    A a2;
};

int main() {
    B bObj;
    bObj.a.print();
    bObj.a2.print();
   return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/C7Vx1X

Comment: Well, it looks what I need. 1) So A a2 call nothing? Or default CTOR?

Comment: @paizza In above code `B bObj;` is calling `B::B()` constructor. In class B constructor I'm calling constructors of class `A::A(int)` for members `A a` and `A a2`.

Comment: I see. But "writing" `A a2` on the public of class `B` what do in fact? Nothing?

Comment: `public` keyword marks all class methods and variable members to be seen outside class scope. If I'd mark them private I'd have to use getters or just use `A a` `A a2` variables only inside B class methods.

Comment: :) I mean, what compiler does when it read `A a2` within the public part of the code? Just init an A object calling its default CTOR?

Comment: `A a2` is initialized inside `B::B()`. Without this initialization it'll try to use `A::A()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116999/discussion-between-paizza-and-paweldac).

Answer (score 1):

In order to simply declare the variable, use the `extern` keyword:

```
extern ILFO obj; //just declaration, no constructor is called.
```

in the .cpp file

```
ILFO obj(blah, blah, blah); //definition
```

This, of course, if you're talking about namespace-scope (including global) variables. If you're talking about class members, then you must know that the constructors of the members are not invoked until the constructor of the class. You can pass the parameters to the constructors in the [constructor initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: I mean: within a class `A` I've the declaration of that `ILFO`. I want to access from all part of `A` to that `ILFO`. But I need to init `ILFO` within the CTOR of `A`. Is it more clear?